# how many remote signals can a RF 433MHz Moduls and a arduino Uno handle?

Tags: arduino

for an art-project I want to control an array of say 60 to 600 lightbulbs. Each lightbulb should have his own radio-remote. So one remote should switches only one bulb on and off.

I want to do this with an arduino Uno. Do you think this is possible? Is there a better choice?

The remotes I thought of using have 8bit encoding.

As I`m only in possession of dangerous half-knowledge, I thought I ask you guys first.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details it is hard to say. I think it would be more appropriate to use only one remote and 600 receivers though. If you have only 8 bit encoding you will be limited to 256 receivers unless you introduce an additional code on top of the existing protocoll.

However you would have to keep in mind that the Arduino has only very limited RAM. So the tight RAM constraints could be another issue.

But unless you provide more details (what are you aiming at, which remotes, how fast do you want to switch the bulbs) it is impossible to provide a better answer.

Comment: Okay Maybe I schould start with a smaller number so just assume 100 Remotes:
I want an audience of like 100 people to each have their own remote, with which they can switch on and off one particular lightbulb each.
And I would hope that they can switch their remote once a second max.

That is the remote I want to use [link] (http://www.miniinthebox.com/de/200m-einzigen-kanal-funkfernbedienung-sender-315-mhz-12v_p271328.html?pos=ultimately_buy_8?pos=ultimately_buy_8)

Regarding the RAM shortage is there a way to calculate the probably needed RAM?